# htaccess rewrite only main domain to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, cpanel

I'm using a cPanel account to host multiple sites. To have a clean public_html, I use .htaccess to redirect the main domain into one of the subfolders.

So when user types in *www.example.com*, it will be rewritten into *www.example.com/mainsite/* but still showing *www.example.com* in the URL.

But when using the codes below, every domain (including sub domains) will get redirected to that folder:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mainsite/$1 [NC,L]
```

How can I target **only** *www.example.com* (and *www.example.com/files*) to be rewritten to the /mainsite?

> *Other subdomains should be pointing to their own Document_Root as created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need one more `RewriteCond` to check for main domain:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mainsite/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mainsite/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Finally working, previously I tried using
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]`
but it only works in homepage but not the subpages.

Answer (score 0):

Do this, This line helps me solve the issue.

```
    # .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect
    # Do not change this line.
    RewriteEngine on
    # Change example.com to be your main domain.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
    # Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/
    # Don't change the following two lines.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1
    # Change example.com to be your main domain again.
    # Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain
    # followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.html [L]
```