# Redirecting from Sub Directory to Root Directory

Tags: .htaccess, serve

I have 2 directories in my public_html directory as **MainSite** & **OtherSite**.

Now I want the following:

1 If  a user enters my domain on it's root address, for instance *www.example.com* he must be redirected to my **MainSite** directory as I have all of the contents there.

2- But if user enters a subaddress, i.e. *www.example.com/othersite*, then he must be redirected to the **OtherSite** directory.
I know 1 can be done easily by pointing this folder for my main domain then in this case where to put my htaccess file and what do I write in that?

I don't want any other directory or sub directory contents to be disturbed.

So, what is a better approach?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Could you show what you have already tried, and where you ran into trouble?

Comment: Let me make it simple
I have my main domain's root directory as MainSite.
I want to write something in htacces file in this folder so that if user enters _www.example.com/othersite_ then he must be shown the contents of OtherSite folder which is 1 level up from MainSite

Comment: I understand, but it's not clear what you have done to solve your problem. Did you try any code? Are you running on a local machine, on a webserver? Etc.

Comment: I am on a webserver

tried a lot of things but for reference you can see these
_https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182490/htaccess-rewrite-only-main-domain-to-subfolder?rq=1_

_https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216109967-Transparently-redirect-your-root-directory-to-a-subdirectory_

Comment: I have tried putting htaccess in my root directory and in **MainSite** folder as well but didn't end up in a solution working.

Comment: What about putting the OrtherSite directory directly in MainSite/othersite? If that is not what you want, try looking into Apache or Nginx

Comment: I can't as I need 2 different PHP versions for these 2 folders